# How to select a specific element after using ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, angularjs

I'm using `ng-repeat` to repeatedly show an element out in `html` based on the array of info I have.

My Controller js:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
 $scope.qnums = [
  {
      data : 'A',
      number : '3456'
  },
  {
      data : 'B',
      number : '1234'
  },
  {
      data : 'C',
      number : '7890'
  },
  {
      data : 'D',
      number : '1122'
  },
  {
      data : 'E',
      number : '6677'
  },
  {
      data : 'F',
      number : '5656'
  }
}]);
```

My html:

```
<div ng-repeat="qnum in qnums">
    <div class="upperreg1">{{qnum.data}}</div>
    <div class="upperreg2">{{qnum.number}}</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make one of the data in the qnum array blink by using the function below:

```
function blink(selector, counter){
    $(selector).fadeOut(500, function(){
        $(this).fadeIn(500, function(){
            if ( counter++ < 10 ) {
                blink(this, counter);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

That means I need an `id` on the element of the array to specify which `qnum` to blink. But there is no element `id` if I use `ng-repeat`. Do you guys know how to do it?

Comment: No need of ID, you can use jQuery `eq()` with `index` to select element.

Comment: How do I put eq() into my blink function?

Comment: use $element rather than selector

Comment: Can you add any fiddle/plnkr?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `eq()` method as mentioned by @Tushar in comments.
give some `class` to `ng-repeat`.then you can pass desired index to blink index.check the below snippet for an idea.

```
        <div ng-repeat="qnum in qnums" class="item">
                <div class="upperreg1">{{qnum.data}}</div>
                <div class="upperreg2">{{qnum.number}}</div>
            </div>

        function blink(index, counter){
            $('.item').eq(index).fadeOut(500, function(){
                $(this).fadeIn(500, function(){
                    if ( counter++ < 10 ) {
                        blink(this, counter);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: Then is it I put blink(1, 10) into my Controller js file? my blink function is on another js file. Can the controller js file reach that function?

Comment: you have to include the other js file before.

Comment: Actually the blink function is under my html file. How do I include in in the Controller js file?

Answer (score 1):

For the manipulation of the **DOM** it is best to use a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/x0x7sc1h/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.numberBlink = 1;
    $scope.qnums = [{
      data: 'A',
      number: '3456'
    }, {
      data: 'B',
      number: '1234'
    }, {
      data: 'C',
      number: '7890'
    }, {
      data: 'D',
      number: '1122'
    }, {
      data: 'E',
      number: '6677'
    }, {
      data: 'F',
      number: '5656'
    }];
  })
  .directive('blink', function() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      scope: {
        counter: "=blink",
        blinkEnable:"="
      },
      link: function(scope, elem) {
        var counter = 0;
        function blink() {
          $(elem).fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(this).fadeIn(500, function() {
              if (counter++ < scope.counter) {
                blink();
              }
            });
          });
        }
        function startBlink(){
           counter=0;
           blink();
        }
        function stopBlink(){
           counter=scope.counter;
        }
        scope.$watch('blinkEnable',function(val){
          if(val)
           startBlink();
          else
           stopBlink();
        });
        
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <div ng-repeat="qnum in qnums">
      <div blink="10" blink-enable="$first">{{qnum.data}}</div>
      <div blink="10" blink-enable="$first">{{qnum.number}}</div>
    </div>
    <b>Dynamic change blink by $index</b>
    <input ng-model="numberBlink">
     <div ng-repeat="qnum in qnums"  blink="10" blink-enable="numberBlink-1==$index">
      <div>{{qnum.data}}</div>
      <div>{{qnum.number}}</div>
    </div>
    
    <b>Dynamic change blink by selected option</b>
    <select ng-model="elementBlink" ng-options="item as item.data for item in qnums"></select>
     <div ng-repeat="qnum in qnums"  blink="10" blink-enable="elementBlink==qnum">
      <div>{{qnum.data}}</div>
      <div>{{qnum.number}}</div>
    </div>
    
    <b>Dynamic change blink by checked</b>
     <div ng-repeat="qnum in qnums" >
      <div blink="10" blink-enable="qnum.checked">{{qnum.data}}</div>
      <div blink="10" blink-enable="qnum.checked">{{qnum.number}}</div>
      <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="qnum.checked"> Blink!</label>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I don't want to blink all the array data. I just want to blink the element of data: A and number:3456. Means that I want to blink one of the array only.

Comment: You can do this by specifying the inclusion of the condition of the directive. I update jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I would use css and ng-class for the blinking.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <div ng-repeat="qnum in qnums" ng-class="{blink:qnum.data===blinkTargetData}">
      <div>{{qnum.data}}</div>
      <div>{{qnum.number}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.blink {
  animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blinker {  
  50% { opacity: 0.0; }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.qnums = [{
      data: 'A',
      number: '3456'
    }, {
      data: 'B',
      number: '1234'
    }, {
      data: 'C',
      number: '7890'
    }, {
      data: 'D',
      number: '1122'
    }, {
      data: 'E',
      number: '6677'
    }, {
      data: 'F',
      number: '5656'
    }];

    $scope.blinkTargetData='B';
  });
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Vivien/tjjfe8q5/)